# Recursively traverse and build a nested dictionary of relationships

Tags: python, recursion

I have a set of objects ("A", "B", "C", "D" in example code), each of which can have relationships to other objects. I want to build a nested dictionary of those relationships.

The code below works, but is restricted to three layers of relationships. In reality I don't know the contents of `rel_dict` and am retrieving the relationships for e.g. object `A` from outside of the system (`rel_dict` is used to create self contained example).

I could add more for loops to assess each layer of the dictionary as its retrieved, but I don't know how many layers are required.

How could I convert this into a recursive function that will retrieve the relationships for an unknown number of layers?

```py
# these relationships are not known, this is provided to mimic results retrieved external from system
rel_dict = {"A": ["B"], "B": ["C", "D"], "C": ["D"], "D": []}


def get_relationships(k):
    rels = rel_dict[k]
    res_dict = {}
    for r in rels:
        res_dict[r] = {}
    return res_dict


def get_relationship_dict(m):
    res_dict = {}
    res_dict[m] = {}
    res_dict[m] = get_relationships(m)

    for m2 in res_dict[m]:
        res_dict[m][m2] = get_relationships(m2)
        for m3 in res_dict[m][m2]:
            res_dict[m][m2][m3] = get_relationships(m3)

    return res_dict
```

Expected output

```py
dep_dict = get_relationship_dict("B")
print(dep_dict)
{'B': {'C': {'D': {}}, 'D': {}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def unpack_tree(root, dag):
    return {node: unpack_tree(node, dag) for node in dag[root]}

def get_relationship_dict(m, dag):
    return {m: unpack_tree(m, dag)}
```

And with your example:

```
>>> get_relationship_dict("B", rel_dict)
{'B': {'C': {'D': {}}, 'D': {}}}
>>>
```

Beware that, if your relationship has a cycle, this code would logically never end, but in practice in it will raise an exception.

---

Besides that, here is a utility class that you can use to mimic a dictionary interface even though you don't actually get your data as a dictionary. It's efficient, in the sense that it will only query the information it needs, and it will do that at most once.

```py
class ExternalDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, f):
        super().__init__()
        self._f = f
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self:
            self[key] = self._f(key)
        return super().__getitem__(key)
```

This is to be used like that:

```
>>> def fetch_relationship(k):
...     return rel_dict[k] # in reality, something else
>>> get_relationship_dict(ExternalDict(fetch_relationship))
{'B': {'C': {'D': {}}, 'D': {}}}
>>>
```

Comment: That's helpful, but I don't have rel_dict to pass into the function. In reality I have to call equivalent to rels = rel_dict[k] which retrieves the relationships from an external service. I therefore have to call it for A, B, C etc separately

Comment: @colebod209 I added something to help you with that too.

Comment: That's great. One last issue, if fetch_relationship needs to take more than one input (e.g. dictionary, auth_token) and could receive more than just dictionary as response (also a response_status) - how would that be best handled?

Comment: I'd create a lambda, ie. `ExternalDict(lambda key: extract_relationship(fetch_relationship(key, auth_token, other_stuff)))` where `extract_relationship` is a function that takes the response, and returns only the wanted dictionary.